# MathJax on a WordPress free blog

Tags: wordpress, mathjax

I have a free WordPress blog with a URL like e.g.

`https://blog.wordpress.com`

I mean I don't have my own domain, only a WP sub-domain.

I noticed that there's a MathJax plugin in WP, but I cannot enable it unless I have a business plan.

So... is there any other way to have MathJax enabled in my blog? With my free account I don't find any way to add some JavaScript tags to the header or to the template of my blog or to anything similar (you see... I would like to have MathJax enabled on all the posts I create).

Is this possible at all with a free WordPress blog like mine?

All I want is to place e.g. these two tags (somewhere... but where?!?!) and get my math working:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" async
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
    </script>
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

MathJax v3 works on [blogspot](https://thuum7.blogspot.com/2019/11/most-efficient-bucket.html) with:

```
<script async id="MathJax-script" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
```

It can work on WP as well.